# Can't get CIAreaHistogram to produce sensible results from video output

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-image, ciimage

I am trying to create a histogram of the output from the camera. I created a AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate class to process the video coming the camera. Below is my captureOutput() function that process the video samples.

```
// AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    if let buffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {
        processUsingCIImage(pixelBuffer: buffer)
    }
}

func processUsingCIImage(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
    let image = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
    let params : [String : Any] = [kCIInputImageKey: image,
                  kCIInputExtentKey: CIVector.init(cgRect: image.extent),
                  "inputCount":16,
                  "inputScale":200]
    let filter = CIFilter(name:"CIAreaHistogram", withInputParameters:params)
    if let outputImage = filter?.outputImage {

        let width = Int(outputImage.extent.width)
        let height = Int(outputImage.extent.height)
        var data = Data(capacity:width*height*4)

        let context = CIContext()
        data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (data: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>) in
            context.render(outputImage, 
                           toBitmap: data, 
                           rowBytes:width*4, 
                           bounds:outputImage.extent, 
                           format:kCIFormatRGBA8, 
                           colorSpace:nil)
            for i in 0..<width {
                print("R:\(data[i*4]) G:\(data[i*4+1]) B:\(data[i*4+2])")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter what the camera preview image is it always outputs

```
R:0 G:0 B:0
```

for all of the values of the histogram apart from the last which appears to be dependent on the image. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Two things. First, have you tried using `CIHistorgramDisplayFilter`? Seems like that would be something to look into. Second, how often are you calling `processUsingCiImage(pixelBuffer:)`? Creating `CIContexts` is very expensive and you are creating one on every single call. While this isn't your current issue, if you are processing a video you probably should create one context and use it everywhere if possible.

Comment: CIHistogramDisplayFilter uses output from CIAreaHistogram so I still need a working CIAreaHistogram first. Secondly this is only an initial implementation. I hadn't got to the point of optimisation. Thanks for the pointer on the CIContext though.

Comment: Last thought? Break things down. You are stating that the issue is with the filter. But in using the filter you are also using `AVCaptureOutput`, and `CVPixelBuffer`. (The latter is something I've used *just* enough to know I'm dangerous!) And if after ruling those things out, maybe provide simplified code that narrows it down to the filter? And good luck!

Comment: I have my own version of the histogram generation, using the CVPixelBuffer which outputs sensible values. I thought the CIAreaHistogram version might be quicker. Was wondering if the issues were related to ColorSpaces as I completely ignore them